# How to enable/download OpenGL on Geforce GTX 750 Ti

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-geforce, opengl, hardware-acceleration, 3d-graphics

For a programming issue I need to install or enable OpenGl on my Geforce GTX 750 Ti video card on a Windows 7 x64 machine. How to know if it's installed or not, and if it's not installed, download it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provided your drivers are up to date, you already have OpenGL support on your [GTX 750 TI card.](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver)

What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: It may be disabled. How to enable it?

Comment: What is the exact problem that leads you to believe it is disabled?  Which API is in use is set individually (you may enable it in Quake, and disable it in  Wolfenstein: Enemy Territory), not system wide.  Do you know which version you need access to (2.0, 3.0, something in-between)?

Comment: I get erros when running an Android emulator for a Qt Quick app saying (I think) that OpenGL is not enabled. For example it's only the last line of the *Application Output* message: **W libtransitions.so: (null):0 ((null)): QOpenGLShaderProgram::uniformLocation(qt_Matrix): shader program is not linked**.

Comment: Please have a look at [this thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76799/why-don-t-advs-work-for-qt-quick-apps/2) for a detailed version of the issue.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean that OpenGL is disabled/not installed, it just means that it is not able to load the shader library that was called.  You should edit your question to reflect the initial problem you're having, and you we would be better able to help you.  Also, note what Android version, device, and developer kit you're using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54716/discussion-between-franky-and-service-manager).

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: It looks to me like you are, indeed, experiencing the emulator bug linked to at the bottom of the above linked off-site thread ( https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-44697 )

Comment: Edits should be used for clarification, not for completely replacing your question. From the [key points of editing](http://superuser.com/help/editing) you should edit a question "To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)". If you have a new question then you should be asking a new question, not rewriting an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL is included in normal drivers.

Comment: What in the?? Yesterday evening the actual question was COMPLETELY different http://superuser.com/posts/1184609/revisions

Comment: @Enigma Although this is a somewhat laconic answer, mirh is right- the original question is completely different. Might be worth a mod flag mirh- not really fair to be penalised for such a drastic change.

Comment: @mirh Don't worry, I've rolled back the question.

Comment: @DavidPostill, you had not that permission to roll back my question. I edited it because that option is valid.

Comment: I don't care what the .. are you doing whether give the question -1000 or not. Instead of it if you think you are able, you would answer the issue.

Comment: And as for the so-called answer, it was not a real answer even for the prvious text of question. It's more like a comment. I didn't ask "is OPengl inculed or not", I rather asked, how to enable it.

Comment: "How do I know if it is installed?"

Comment: @franky You have been asked to **not** radically change your question, and I have explained why. Please stop changing it.

Comment: 1- This is not irrelevant to the prior text, rather it's more accurate 2- I don't have to accept your suggestion. 3- Read the comments right below the question for figuring out the reason of changing the text.

Comment: OK, if you apply forces, (like trump) this is not my question anymore and I do not want any comments/answers for this and will never accept any response on it

Comment: Could somebody explain in the first place the point in basically flip-flopping so much the question?